# cypress-wait-until: Catch 'errorMsg' if exceeds 'timeout'?

Tags: cypress

Using [npm module cypress-wait-until](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until), **is there a way to catch `errorMsg` if `cy.waitUntil()` has completed all possible intervals and exceeded timeout?** Thereby, providing a point of failure.

Example code waiting for an entry to be found in a log. Custom command `cy.cmdAvailable()` response is `Chainable<boolean>`, returns `true` when a specific service is yet available, else `false`:

```js
cy.waitUntil(() => cy.cmdAvailable()), {
  errorMsg: 'ERROR: Not Available',
  verbose: true,
  customCheckMessage: 'CHECK: Availability'
}).then($status => {
  expect($status).to.be.a('boolean');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`cy.waitUntil()` always throws an error on timeout, so options are limited.

You could precede the command with a listener on the fail event - Recipe [Error handling](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/697985ec4be8ecde7b5d6f4170c1612b1ab8b806/examples/fundamentals__errors/cypress/integration/test-fails.js#L19)

If you want the status inside `.then()`, use a flag variable,

```js
let failed = false;

cy.once('fail', (event, runnable) => {
  if (e.message.includes('ERROR: Not Available')) {
    failed = true;
    return false  // not fail on this message
  })
})

cy.waitUntil(() => cy.cmdAvailable()), {
  errorMsg: 'ERROR: Not Available',
  verbose: true,
  customCheckMessage: 'CHECK: Availability'
}).then(() => {
  // use failed here
})
```

It's possible `.then()` does not get actioned because previous chained command failed.

If so, separate it from `cy.waitUntil()`

```js
cy.waitUntil(() => cy.cmdAvailable()), {
  errorMsg: 'ERROR: Not Available',
  verbose: true,
  customCheckMessage: 'CHECK: Availability'
})

cy.then(() => {
  // use failed here
})
```